# Regular expression to remove brackets and text before pipe symbol - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want a regular expression to remove brackets and text untill `|` symbol from a string

input : `hello [[aa-a]] bbb [[ccc|ddd]] eee [[fff|ggg]] hhh [[iii]] jjj`

expected output : `hello [[aa-a]] bbb ddd eee ggg hhh [[iii]] jjj`

I want to do it repeatedly wherever such patterns are present inside a text string ..

Comment: Can you post your so far tried code ?

Comment: **preg_replace("/(?s)(?<=\\[[).*?(?<\\|)/","",$text)**

Comment: read updated comment with answer to updated post

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$html = '[[Erzbistum Köln | kirchlicher Macht]]';
preg_match('/\|(.*)]]$/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //kirchlicher Macht
```

for check :-

```
if(preg_match('/\|(.*)]]$/', $yourstring)) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: THANKS ... But can you just have a look into the edited question's input and output ? I want something like that ... also repeatedly..

Comment: yes you can use it repeatedly try it and let me know

Comment: yes i see you can check my updated answer also it will match pattern in any string

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text = 'Sitz weltlicher und insbesondere [[Erzbistum Köln|kirchlicher Macht]] trugen';
$text = preg_replace('/\[\[.*?\|(.*?)\]\]/', '\\1', $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Sitz weltlicher und insbesondere kirchlicher Macht trugen
```

Comment: Hi ... 
$text = '[[aa-a]] bbb [[ccc|ddd]] eee [[fff|ggg]] hhh [[iii]] jjj ';
$text = preg_replace('/\[\[.*?\|(.*?)\]\]/', '\\1', $text);
echo $text;

output : ddd eee ggg hhh [[iii]] jjj 
expected : aa-a bbb ddd eee ggg hhh [[iii]] jjj 

can you help ???

Comment: Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard string functions in this case without regular expressions.

Example:

```
<?php
$in = "[[Erzbistum Köln | kirchlicher Macht]]";
$out = substr( $in, strpos($in, "|") );
echo trim($out,"[]| ");
```

see result: http://codepad.org/XsNVu6fJ

To updated case you can use this code

```
<?php

$in = "Sitz weltlicher und insbesondere [[Erzbistum Köln|kirchlicher Macht]] trugen";
$out = preg_replace("/\\[\\[.+\\|(.+)\\]\\]/i", "$1", $in);

echo $out;
```

see result: http://codepad.org/KVFcaO3K